# Memory Cache for a social network

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-core, redis

everyone.

I am creating a social network from scratch, it is open source and you can find the code [here](https://github.com/anteatergames/indievisible).

You can see it live in production environment [here](https://www.indievisible.net).

It is hosted at Azure (App Service), I am using AspNet Core Mvc as the base with MongoDb Atlas as persistence.

My problem is that I need some information from the users almost across the whole application like the user Full Name, for example. So getting these data from the database all the time uses a lot of resources and slows down the whole solution.

Example:

The UserContentComment document saves the UserId (Guid) but when I render the comments, I must show the user current FullName, the most recent profile changes must reflect across the platform.

I thought about solving this issue using a memory cache and Microsoft recommends two options:

- IMemoryCache;
- A distributed cache (SQL or Redis);

Well, I really don't want to go for the distributed cache solutions due to the lack of funds to afford the costs of running the whole thing on the cloud. So I thought about using IMemoryCache.

The problem here is that it is a key/value storage and I need to store now just the full name but I am afraid of other stuff I might need to store like location, age, etc.

The key format here would be something like this:

```
{ Key:"7df21e7a-5dba-4635-bc39-08d7493f75dc_fullname", Value: "John Doe"}
{ Key:"7df21e7a-5dba-4635-bc39-08d7493f75dc_age", Value: "25"}
{ Key:"7df21e7a-5dba-4635-bc39-08d7493f75dc_location", Value: "Atlantis"}
```

Or I can store whole objects

```
{ Key:"7df21e7a-5dba-4635-bc39-08d7493f75dc", Value: johnprofile}
```

Is it a good practice to store this kind of information this way?

Do you guys have any suggestion to improve from here?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Use session if you only want to cache data on the logged in user https://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/ otherwise, you can use an IMemoryCache to cache data on users if you need to be able to pull the FullName of any user, but I would stick to an injected interface so that you can replace it with another implementation later (like redis) when it becomes necessary.